# Django, how serve media(users) files using nginx?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, vps, production

I'am struggling with my nginx configuration. Using docker-compose I deployed my Django app to vps. Static files works fine but I cant set up correctly media files. Below are my conf files:

setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

nginx conf file:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/www/book_store/media/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  nginx:
    #other commands
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    depends_on:
      - web
 web:
    #other commands
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
```

error message when app trying to access media file (message from nginx container):

> ng01     | 2018/11/26 15:52:37 [error] 5#5: *6 open()
>   "/home/www/book_store/media/default.png" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: XX.XX.XXX.XXX, server: localhost, request: "GET
>   /media/default.png HTTP/1.1", host: "XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8000", referrer:
>   "http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXXX:8000/users/user/profile/"

Comment: is the `default.png` file on the media folder?

Comment: What's BASE_DIR? In general, if it's the location of your "manage.py" file, then I would not expect it to be */home/www/book_store/* because in standard Django projects there's an additional "source" directory below the main directory. You normally don't want uploaded media files to end up in your source directory since that messes up version control. So I think your `MEDIA_ROOT` doesn't match your nginx location. Check via ssh where the media directory was actually created by Django and where it put the uploaded file *default.png*.

Comment: The problem was that I mount /media/ in docker-compose.yml and then I used bad alias /home/www/book_store/media/;